# MSDOS Scripted directory name with date and time

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I need to back up files by creating a .zip directory. The name of the directory must have the date(YYYYMMDD) and time(HHMMSS). Below is my code:

```
set folder_files_rar=C:\Program Files\zip
set folder_save_files=in10xml_uploaded
set datetime =%date:~6.4%%date:~3.2%%date:~0.2%%time:~0.2%%time:~3.2%% time:~6.2%
set xml_uploaded_folder=C:\xml\UPLOADED
Set xml_uploading_folder=C:\xml\UPLOADING
Set xml_files_extension=xml
cls
CD\
cd "%% folder_files_rar"

rar m% xml_uploaded_folder% \% folder_save_files% _% datetime% .rar% xml_uploading_folder% \ *.% xml_files_extension%
```

When I run this script file name out only with the date (results below). The time does not come out and need her skirt.

in10xml_uploaded_YYYYMMDD

I need you to go out like this: in10xml_uploaded_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to remove the spaces before and after % signs for a start